# JAVA8: Map list of objects to String[]

Tags: java, java-8

I have a List of 'Client' objects each one with a field "email".

I need something like:

```
List<String> listEmails = clients.stream().map(client->client.getEmail())
                                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

...but returning directly a `String[]`.

Is there a proper way to map a `List<Client>` to a `String[] listEmails` using Java 8 streams?

Comment: loop through the list and store the email in String array

Comment: I would like to obtain the String[] directly if it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure :

```
String[] result = clients
  .stream()
  .map(client->client.getEmail())
  .toArray(String[]::new)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clean and concise answer! I didn't know about the .toArray(String[]::new) trick.